# Where Global members are defined?

Tags: vb.net

I copy the whole folders from a VB.NET project to a different folder because a need to start a new project based on an older version but since the name of the new project is new also I need to change all the old name references to.

So I manually change the text replacing the proper text but on file FrmConfig.Designer.vb there some text that are marked as error.

Example:

```
Me.TxtSQLString.Text = Global.MyProgram1_root.My.MySettings.Default.CnnSQL
```

I change it to

```
Me.TxtSQLString.Text = Global.Fast_TCP_root.My.MySettings.Default.CnnSQL
```

So, Where Global members are located?

I need to update their names.

Comment: *those* variables are part of `My.Settings`; you should define them in the new project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are Settings as evidenced by the `My.MySettings` portion in the name.  When you define them in the Settings Editor, the designer encodes them differently than a normal variable:

```
<Global.System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute(), _
 Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
 Global.System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")> _
Public Property Ziggy() As String
    Get
        Return CType(Me("Ziggy"), String)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me("Ziggy") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

As you can see, "Ziggy" becomes a Property, not a plain variable.  So to use the same Settings in a new project, you should (re)define them via the Settings Editor rather than trying to copy a file.

---

You should not try to import/copy the old setting items because these are managed and generated by VS.  The top of the designer file provides a warning:

> This code was generated by a tool.
>
> Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
>     the code is regenerated.

Comment: So, I must to delete them and re write it?

Comment: There's any way to rename a project and its folder better than I'm doing it?

Comment: you arent renaming a project, you copied some files/folders and started over.  You dont have to delete anything, just define them again in the Settings Editor.

Comment: That's the point, I need to change the name of the application too. That's why I change those text manually; I know if messy but I can't figure out a better way to do it.

Comment: if you copied the *entire* solution folder, the Settings should have come along. Then change the name via Project Properties; maybe delete \bin and \obj; Clean and Rebuild and things should work ok.   Are there like zillions of Settings that recreating them is a chore?